# Calculating an average using a ValueTransformerWithKey Or can I use Kafka's aggregation functions

Tags: aggregate, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stream of objects where I'd like to calculate the average of a field in this object and then save that average back onto the object. I'd like to have a tumbling window of 5 minutes with a retention of 1 hour.  I'm new to Kafka so I'm wondering if this is the correct way to approach the problem.

First, I create a persistent store:

```java
StoreBuilder<WindowStore<String, Double>> averagesStoreSupplier =
    Stores.windowStoreBuilder(
        Stores.persistentWindowStore(WINDOW_STORE_NAME, Duration.ofHours(1), Duration.ofMinutes(5), true),
        Serdes.String(),
        Serdes.Double());

streamsBuilder.addStateStore(averagesStoreSupplier);
```

Then I call my transformer using:

```java
otherKTable
    .leftJoin(objectKTable.transformValues(new AveragingTransformerSupplier(WINDOW_STORE_NAME), WINDOW_STORE_NAME), 
            myValueJoiner)
    .to("outputTopic")
```

And here is my transformer:

```java
public class AveragingTransformerSupplier implements ValueTransformerWithKeySupplier<String, MyObject, MyObject> {

    private final String stateStoreName;

    public TelemetryAveragingTransformerSupplier(final String stateStoreName) {
        this.stateStoreName = stateStoreName;
    }

    public ValueTransformerWithKey<String, MyObject, MyObject> get() {
        return new ValueTransformerWithKey<>() {

            private WindowStore<String, Double> averagesStore;

            @Override
            public void init(ProcessorContext processorContext) {
                averagesStore = Try.of(() ->(WindowStore<String, Double>) processorContext.getStateStore(stateStoreName)).getOrElse((WindowStore<String, Double>)null);
            }

            @Override
            public MyObject transform(String s, MyObject myObject) {
                if (averagesStore != null) {
                    averagesStore.put(s, myObject.getNumber());

                    Instant timeFrom = Instant.ofEpochMilli(0); // beginning of time = oldest available
                    Instant timeTo = Instant.now();
                    WindowStoreIterator<Double> itr = averagesStore.fetch(s, timeFrom, timeTo);

                    double sum = 0.0;
                    int size = 0;
                    while(itr.hasNext()) {
                        KeyValue<Long, Double> next = itr.next();
                        size++;
                        sum += next.value;
                    }

                    myObject.setNumber(sum / size);

                }

                return myObject;
            }

            @Override
            public void close() {
                if (averagesStore != null) {
                    averagesStore.flush();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I have a couple of questions.
First, is the way I define the WindowStore the correct way to form a tumbling window?  How would I create a hopping window?

Second, inside my transformer I get all the items from the store from the beginning of time to now.  Since I defined it as a 5 minute window and 1 hour retention does that mean that the items in the store is a snapshot of 5 minutes worth of data?  What does the retention do here?

I have this working on trivial cases, but not sure if there is a better way to do this using aggregations and joins or even if I'm doing this correctly.  Also I had to surround the retrieval of getting the store in a try catch because the init gets called multiple times and sometimes I get `Processor has no access to StateStore` exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use the DSL instead of the Processor API for this use case. Cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Stream+Usage+Patterns for details.

> I have a couple of questions. First, is the way I define the WindowStore the correct way to form a tumbling window? How would I create a hopping window?

A windowed store can be used for either hopping or tumbling window -- it depends how you *use* it in your processor, not how you create the store, what window semantics you get.

> Second, inside my transformer I get all the items from the store from the beginning of time to now. Since I defined it as a 5 minute window and 1 hour retention does that mean that the items in the store is a snapshot of 5 minutes worth of data? What does the retention do here?

The parameter `windowSize` when you create the store does not work the way you expect it. You would need to code up the windowing logic manually in your `Transformer` code by using `put(key, value, windowStartTimestamp)` -- atm, you are using `put(key, value)` that uses `context.timestamp()`, ie, the current record timestamp, as windowStartTimestamp -- I doubt that is what you want. The retention time is based on the window timestamps, ie, old windows will be deleted after they expire.